# Flash Fullscreen not working in Flash player versions 9.0.47.0 and 9.0.28.0

Tags: flash, video, actionscript-2

The fullscreen functionality for my Flash video player does not work in Flash player versions  9.0.47.0 and 9.0.28.0. It works on all other versions 9.0.115.0 and above. On clicking the fullscreen button, the function gets triggered but the video does not go fullscreen, it stretches inside the video player. Is there any additional handling required for Flash player 9.0.47.0 and 9.0.28.0 ?
(flash code is in Actionscript 2)

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps this is a bug in those versions, which (among others) led to the release of newer versions?

Comment: Our of curiosity, have you been able to reproduce this issue on FF, Safari, etc or is it just IE?

Answer (score 1):

This may have to do with full-screen mode not being originally supported when wmode is opaque or transparent windowless; newer versions of the Flash Player (9.0.64 should be sufficient, 9.0.115 definitely is) fix this issue.

Also note that you must have version 9,0,115,0 or later for hardware-scaled full-screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

Some 9.x version are very bugy. Check that your visitor has at least 9.0.115 - that's very stable version.

I recommend [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) for that. It embeds the SWF and also lets you specify which version is needed + there is an express install option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug of the flash player. We had a lot of problem with socket connections (loading the policy file) with flash player version under 9.0.115.

But, on our page we having just a few people using this old versions of the flash player, they are quite uncommon, most people have newer ones.